# Intellij IDEA Dependencies Tool Window Missing

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When using Intellij IDEA previously for a maven project, it had what I assume was a built in dependency tool that would show me a simple list of all of my dependencies and allow me to upgrade any of them to the latest versions with a simple click of a button. I have need to perform major updates to my application, and I can no longer find this.

According to documentation that I've found on JetBrains own website, the module I'm looking for is the [Dependencies Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/guide/java/tutorials/managing-dependencies/update-dependencies/).

[image: Text]

According to that documentation, this can be opened using the Quick Launch at the bottom left. However, it says that I need to open a module called "Dependency". However, I don't have an option for this. I just have "Dependency Viewer", which is not even close to the same thing. Hell, far as I can tell, Dependency Viewer has nothing to do with my project's Maven dependencies. It doesn't list anything I've added to my project, it just shows me some custom Java class files I set up for Hibernate Dialects.

[image]

My current version of Intellij IDEA is 2023.2.1 (Ultimate Edition), Build #IU-232.9559.62.

I am behind on the upgrades, but this current version I'm using led to this problem in the first place, and broke half of my plugins so I've been very hesitant to perform another upgrade.

Do I need to downgrade IDEA to restore this functionality? I know I had a 222.* build previously the last time I used this feature. I assume what I'm looking for isn't a plugin based on the JetBrains articles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the answer from the [related issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-325749/Dependencies-tool-window-seems-to-be-removed#focus=Comments-27-7880710.0-0):

> Please install [Package Search](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12507-package-search) plugin from the Marketplace, it is just not bundled. We are in the middle of its redesign.

Answer (score 0):

As listed on the documentation page for [Package Search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/package-search.html), this requires the Package Search plugin. Make sure this plugin is installed & enabled.